# getChildCount() of Android ExpandableListView odd behaviour

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an ExpandableListView which I've been using for a while in some of my apps now.
Recently however, I had to set the layout param of it as follows:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

since in this particular instance of the listview i have very few children. When I load the app at first, everything is working properly, and the height of the listview is exactly as much as it's children.

Then I added an EditText box above my list. Naturally, the keyboard appears and pushes up the listview. Lets say it has 8 children total. When the keyboard has been pressed 2 of them become invisible and the getChildCount() method returns 6, and a scrollbar appears, allowing me to view the 2 invisible ones.

The problem is, that when i get the keyboard out of the screen, the listview retains it's scrollbar and getChildCount() keeps returning 6, even though it now has enough space to stretch its layout to the way it wass on app start...
I rely very heavily on getChildCount to perform some calculations in onMeasure() and this behaviour is totally bugging everything.
Any insight as to why this is happening and how i could fix it?

Comment: Most likely the value returned by `getChildCount()` is correct. I think your assumption about what this value means is wrong. Also **NEVER** do this: `android:layout_height="wrap_content" ` on a `ListView`. You should use a `LinearLayout`. If you are lazy you can even write some code to populate the `LinearLayout` from the `Adapter`.

Comment: Thanks! Didnt know about wrap_content and android lists.